# Flask update a global variable with value from Redis

Tags: python, flask, redis, global-variables

I have a python flask app with a global variable reading some data from Redis. I have another process that's updating data in Redis independently, and it will ping the flask app (i.e. endpoint /reload-redis-data) to tell flask app to update that global variable with the latest data in Redis.

There are 3 files involved:

- app.py

```
from re import A
from flask import Flask
from util import load_redis_config
from function import f

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello world!"

@app.route("/test")
def test():
    f()
    return ""

@app.route("/reload-redis-config")
def reload_redis_config():
    load_redis_config()
    return "reloaded"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run("localhost", 3001)
```

- util.py

```
import redis

global a
a = ""

def load_redis_config():
    con = redis.Redis("localhost", 6379)
    global a
    a = eval(con.get("a"))
    print(f"Updated {a=}")

load_redis_config()
print(f"At server start {a=}")
```

- function.py

```
from util import a

def f():
    global a
    print(f"In function f {a=}")
```

The setup is:

1. in Redis `set a 1`
2. at server start, `load_redis_config()` will be called and load `a` -> print 1
3. /test -> print 1
4. in Redis `set a 2`
5. ping `/reload-redis-config`, `load_redis_config()` will print `a` is changed to 2
6. /test -> I'm expecting it to be changed to 2 since `a` is a global variable which is updated in step 5, but within function f `a` is still 1.

My trace:

```
Updated a=1
At server start a=1
 * Serving Flask app 'app'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://localhost:3001
Press CTRL+C to quit
In function f a=1
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Oct/2022 14:22:21] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Updated a=2
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Oct/2022 14:22:32] "GET /reload-redis-config HTTP/1.1" 200 -
In function f a=1
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Oct/2022 14:22:35] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Basically my question is, why `function` isn't picking up the updated global variable `a`? Is there anything or any concept that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your `function.py` file is rendered once when the server starts, and after that, only the function `f()` is rendered when `/test` is called. Since you only import the variable `a` once in the `function.py` script and that is also rendered only when the server starts, the script does not check if it is updated in the `util.py` again when `f()` is called.

To solve this, in your `util.py`:

```py
import redis

global a
a = ""

def load_redis_config():
    con = redis.Redis("localhost", 6379)
    global a
    a = eval(con.get("a"))
    print(f"Updated {a=}")

def get_a():
    return a

load_redis_config()
print(f"At server start {a=}")
```

In You `function.py`

```py
from util import get_a

def f():
    a = get_a()
    print(f"In function f {a=}")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried and it's now working and updating the variable correctly! Always good to learn something new :D